# selection of task in release pipeline in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a build pipeline which I created and I have the artifacts in a drop folder. 
Now I want to deploy these artifacts. The drop folder contains my data factory resources like pipelines, datasets.

I have 2 questions:

1. What task for the agent should I select in the release pipeline to deploy this folder?
2. How do I specify that in this environment it should go ? i.e. If I suppose have a QA environment, then how do I specify that thing?

I am actually confused over this selection of task for the agent.

Answer (score 0):

> What task for the agent should I select in the release pipeline to
>   deploy this folder?

It's based on where and how you want to deploy the artifacts.
If you just want to deploy them in a local machine where you can access, then you just need to add a [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the artifacts to the target folder.

If you want to deploy to other remote sites or third party services, then you need to select other tasks based on your requirements, and some of them we need to create [services connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to access them. 
For example [Deploy to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/deploy-azure/?view=azure-devops)(e.g. [Deploy a web app to Azure App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps?view=azure-devops))

> How do I specify that in this environment it should go ? i.e. If I
>   suppose have a QA environment, then how do I specify that thing?

In release pipeline we can defined multiple environments/stages, in each environment we can add different tasks to do the actions based on our requirements. We need to add the artifacts sources to deploy them in the release pipeline. Please see [Release pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops) for details. You can reference below links to do that:

- [Reference Exercise 2: Examine the CI/CD pipelines configured by
  Azure DevOps Project](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azuredevopsprojectdotnet/#exercise-2-examine-the--cicd-pipelines-configured-by-azure-devops-project)
- [Azure DevOps - creating a release pipeline- Video Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0gpZCwJA5Q)

Comment: I have data factory resources to deploy like pipelines and datasets. So i would like to deploy them to another data factory.

Comment: There's a detailed guild which deploy data factory resources, please check if that helps : https://azure.microsoft.com/mediahandler/files/resourcefiles/whitepaper-adf-on-azuredevops/Azure%20data%20Factory-Whitepaper-DevOps.pdf